# Why does std::is_same give a different result for the two types?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-function, template-argument-deduction

In the code below, why do the two ways of invoking `fun`: `fun(num)` and `fun<const int>(num)`, give a different result when compiling?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename = typename enable_if<!std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type>
void fun(T val)
{
    cout << val << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int num = 42;
    fun(num);  //ERROR!

    fun<const int>(num);  //Right

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An `int` prvalue is never const qualified.

Answer (score 20):

The parameter is declared as pass-by-value; then in [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call), the top-level const qualifier of the argument is ignored.

> Before deduction begins, the following adjustments to P and A are
>   made:
>
> 1) If P is not a reference type,
>
> a) ...
>
> b) ...
>
> c) otherwise, if A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers
>   are ignored for deduction:

So given `fun(num)`, the template parameter `T` will be deduced as `int`, not `const int`.

If you change the parameter to pass-by-reference, the `const` part will be preserved. e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename = typename enable_if<!std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type>
void fun(T& val)
```

Then for `fun(num)`, `T` will be deduced as `const int`.

Comment: What's more, the type of `num` is `const int`, the type of the value of `num` is just `int`. There is no such thing a value (a prvalue, technically) of type `const int`.